# Why doesn't /usr/libexec/java_home recognize JDK 1.8?

Tags: macos, install, java

I am trying to install a JDK 8 on OS X Mountain Lion (to experiment with the new lambda features).

## Starting point

A machine recently updated from OS X 10.6 to 10.8, with

```
$ sw_vers
  ProductName:    Mac OS X
  ProductVersion: 10.8.2
  BuildVersion:   12C60

$ ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
  Home@ -> jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home/
  jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/

$ ls -l /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
  1.6.0.jdk/
```

and this folder from the OS X 10.6 era:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
```

In ~/.bashrc I've set

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Home
```

So I have

```
$ java -version
  java version "1.7.0_09"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

$ /usr/libexec/java_home
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
```

## How I installed JDK 8

1. Downloaded the .tar.gz file from http://jdk8.java.net/lambda/ and unpacked it into

   - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home

   (I created the folders `jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home` manually)
2. Changed the symlink `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Home` to point to jdk1.8

Now I have

```
$ java -version
  openjdk version "1.8.0-ea"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-lambda-nightly-h2135-20121203-b67-b00)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b05, mixed mode)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/Home

$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
  Home@ -> jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/
  ...
```

But the `java_home` utility doesn't seem to care:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home 
  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_09.jdk/Contents/Home
```

It doesn't even know that there is a JDK 8 available:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*
  Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8*".
```

## Question

I'd like the `/usr/libexec/java_home` utility to find my installed JDKs, so I can use something like this:

```
alias setjdk17='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7*)'
alias setjdk18='export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*)'
```

and get rid of the `Home` symlink. Does anyone know

- how I can properly install JDK 8?
- how I can make `/usr/libexec/java_home` recognize it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to also copy the Contents/MacOS directory and Info.plist from the 1.7 SDK and adapt them (by changing the version strings in it).

Then you can:

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0-ea"
$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8*
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Note that this is a hack and I didn't try anything else than start java... I was just building on your tip of creating the package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Anjo. I'll give it a try as soon as I fixed my OS X 10.8 system (which is now broken: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86601/login-loop-after-os-x-10-8-update-windowserver-problem]).